# Django: alternative to using annotate(Count()) for speed

Tags: django, django-models

There are two models with a one to many relationship, A->{B}. I am counting how many records of A I have with the same B after using a filter(). Then I need to extract the top X records of A in terms of the most B records connected to them.

The current code:

```
class A(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    ...

data = B.objects.all().filter(...)

top = data.values('a',...).annotate(n=Count('a')).distinct().order_by('-n')[:X];
```

I have ~300k B records and with my laptop this is taking ~2s for one query. I dissected the query into parts and timed it and it seems the main bottleneck is the annotate().

Is there any way whatsoever to do this faster with Django?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `.select_related('a')` before `annotate` in the queryset. This will force django to join the models before counting them.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: If I do that before the values() call (impossible after), the time remains about the same. Or did you mean I need to do this before the filter() and then a group of calls will be faster?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the SQL with `print(data.sql)`?

Comment: I'm not sure you _want_ the A model joined in this instance: we aren't using anything from the A model other than it's primary key, which is already in the B table.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the slow down is actually in the `DISTINCT`, rather than the count.

The way django builds up a query when using `queryset.values(x).annotate(...)` tells it to group by the first values, and then perform the aggregate.

```
B.objects.filter(...).values('a').annotate(n=Count('*')).order_by('-n')[:10]
```

That should generate SQL that looks something like:

```
SELECT b.a, 
       count(*) AS n
  FROM b
 GROUP BY (b.a)
 ORDER BY count(*) DESC
 LIMIT 10
```